# Multiple posts categorized by day?

Tags: customization, archives

I would like to set up my home page so that multiple post uploads (with no limit to the number of posts which can be uploaded) can be categorized by the day. These post uploads will mostly be videos, although some may be text posts.

[Here's an example of what I mean.](http://www.boobootv.com/)

Can this be done using archives?

Comment: posts are already by default ordered by date in archives.

Comment: @Milo So is the site I referenced essentially using the 'archive' template on the home page?

Comment: I don't know what template that is, but [any query you create](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) will [default to ordering by date](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) if another order isn't specified.

Comment: @Milo If I create a query (which would get sorted by date by default), would it be possible to style the day the post was posted like in the example I linked? In other words, does WordPress spit out the date by default?